# PostgresSQL - How to connect to local machine

Tags: postgresql

I installed Postgres to try it and I would like to use my laptop as server.
I clicked on 'Add a connection to a server' and the form 'New Server Registration' opens but I don't know how to fill it out.
What user should I use, myself or postgres? Should I set up a password?
Can someone please explain in very basic terms how to set up my laptop as server and connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask depends on a number of things including OS, version etc. If this is Ubuntu server, starting instructions are in the server guide, and they work. In essence, by default tcp access to postgres needs to be enabled. PostgreSQL configuration files are at /etc/postgres//main. At this location pg_hba.conf handles the host based access settings where tcp access may be enabled. This and a couple of other files need to be edited as per Ubuntu server guide to get working access to postgres server on localhost.

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to follow the Ubuntu server guide but I am not sure what I achieved doing that. When I open pgAdmin III I cannot establish a connection with my laptop. I am used to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio where it is quite easy to connect to the local machine and no settings are required. Any more basic advice would be appreciated.